# QGIS bar chart with labels

Tags: qgis

I am trying to get a simple bar chart on my QGIS 2.6 map. I have done that with diagrams.
It seems to me it is not possible to add simple values to each bar (say there are three bars at a point). I have tried the Dialog plugin, but it only creates a picture file in the print composer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a HTML frame from Google Charts in QGIS

Note:
If you update your chart attributes you need to click 'Refresh HTML' before exporting again in the print composer.

[image]