# Creating a bar chart in QGIS 3 from a list attribute

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

I have a layer from a PostGIS database which has a `FLOAT[]` data type (list of floats), and I would like to draw a bar chart with vertical bars for each element in the list, sequentially. Kind of like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227245/bar-column-charts-with-values), but the data would be a time series rather than a qualitative binning.

The only two resources I can find for this are:

- ["QGIS bar chart with labels"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143764/qgis-bar-chart-with-labels) - whose only answer is to use Google sheets (unacceptable for my use case)
- [Bar / Column Charts with values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227245/bar-column-charts-with-values) - closer, but the D3 render plugin only seemed to add an option to make some kind of heatmap in QGIS 3.

I can see that you can make a histogram under Layer Properties > Diagrams, but I need a bar chart drawing sequential values from a list attribute, and I have no idea how to begin.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Here is some sample data that you can insert into a PostGIS database that looks like what I have on-hand. It contains 10 random points with 10 values in each list.

```
CREATE TABLE barchart_test_data (id TEXT, "data" FLOAT[], geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO barchart_test_data (id,"data",geom) VALUES 
('205','{0.4245885,0.36127677517499995,0.3081234165981712,0.2634985144049946,0.3656251777687132,0.3117741179957232,0.4061549607633094,0.3458008973088364,0.2951306433356336,0.3921819316124312}','POINT (1.0493663176894188 1.0493663176894188)')
,('329','{0.56418,0.618062319,0.66329921991645,0.7012778600808557,0.7331628274308825,0.7599318517695974,0.7824057861531655,0.8012737777648901,0.8171144001225135,0.8304133946228562}','POINT (1.0612912280485034 1.0612912280485034)')
,('256','{0.4245885,0.500868275175,0.4253174604231712,0.5014802738982733,0.5654227639512954,0.6191056814753101,0.6641751748825966,0.702013268072684,0.7337802392104219,0.7604501998291097}','POINT (1.1211415464058518 1.1211415464058518)')
,('120','{0.4245885,0.36127677517499995,0.3081234165981712,0.40309001440499465,0.3432277215937133,0.432561833664002,0.3679707874526129,0.3137433746058412,0.26821675015033397,0.22999487258871287}','POINT (1.1356072491034865 1.1356072491034865)')
,('251','{0.56418,0.478470819,0.54610517609145,0.602887600587577,0.5109677850733003,0.5733880039582893,0.6257928987231818,0.5301979281230472,0.5895326705557044,0.6393471535650416}','POINT (1.334024685434997 1.334024685434997)')
,('24','{0.4245885,0.36127677517499995,0.3081234165981712,0.2634985144049946,0.22603367776871322,0.19458007417072318,0.16817320127003063,0.1460033111262542,0.1273905798560467,0.11176426131814401}','POINT (1.3527626814320683 1.3527626814320683)')
,('38','{0.4245885,0.36127677517499995,0.3081234165981712,0.2634985144049946,0.22603367776871322,0.3341715741707232,0.28536724509503064,0.24439357061953298,0.20999412221362893,0.18111406530445218}','POINT (1.3899430576711893 1.3899430576711893)')
,('263','{0.56418,0.618062319,0.66329921991645,0.7012778600808557,0.7331628274308825,0.6203403517695975,0.6652117423281655,0.5632920182716113,0.47772531393993134,0.40588778731826936}','POINT (1.3972668061032891 1.3972668061032891)')
,('326','{0.56418,0.618062319,0.66329921991645,0.7012778600808557,0.7331628274308825,0.7599318517695974,0.7824057861531655,0.8012737777648901,0.8171144001225135,0.8304133946228562}','POINT (1.4661570535972714 1.4661570535972714)')
,('8','{0.4245885,0.36127677517499995,0.3081234165981712,0.2634985144049946,0.22603367776871322,0.19458007417072318,0.16817320127003063,0.1460033111262542,0.1273905798560467,0.11176426131814401}','POINT (1.47384490724653 1.47384490724653)')
;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create histogram to visualize feature's value in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352859/how-to-create-histogram-to-visualize-features-value-in-qgis-3)

Comment: @Erik - no, when you have a list attribute, it doesn't even appear in the attribute input parameter. Also, I think this only makes histograms, whereas I want to make a time series, with each element in the list being the next time step.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an elegant solution, but I'm sharing it with you anyway because it works.

The idea is to create a bar for each value so in your case 10 bars. To do this, you add an expression and you use the `array_get("field",index)` function. To retrieve the first value, you write `array_get("data",0)`. Do this for each value.

[image]